# New strong parameter not being saved in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I added a new column named "version" to a table in Rails using a migration and manually added the corresponding parameter to the strong parameters permitted in the corresponding controller:

```
def endpoint_params
params.require(:endpoint).permit(:hostname, :username, :password, :connection_string, :entity_id, :created_at,
                                 :updated_at, :endpoint_type_id, :endpoint_app_id, :environment_id, :created_by,
                                 :updated_by, :version)
end
```

However, when I try to set that new parameter in the update action and save it to the database, it doesn't get saved at all. The code that I'm using is:

```
def update

begin

  @environment = Environment.find(params[:env])

  version_no = (EndpointsFile.where("environment_id = ?", @environment.id).maximum('version') || 0) + 1

  @endpoint.updated_by = current_user.id
  @endpoint.version = version_no

  respond_to do |format|

    if @endpoint.update(endpoint_params)

      @endpoints = Endpoint.where("environment_id = ? and id <> ?", @environment.id, @endpoint.id)

      EndpointsFile.create!(version: version_no, date: Time.now, environment_id: @environment.id)

      @endpoints.each do |e|

        e.version = version_no
        e.save

        puts "e.version: #{e.version}"   **=> HERE IT PRINTS e.version: and the field is null in the database**

      end

      format.html { redirect_to env_endpoints_path(env: @environment.id), notice: t('.notice') }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @endpoint }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @endpoint.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end

  rescue => exception

    logger.error { "endpoints_controller.update -> Ocorreu um erro ao atualizar o endpoint: #{exception.message}" }

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to env_endpoints_path(env: @environment.id), alert: "Ocorreu um erro ao atualizar o endpoint: #{exception.message}" and return }
       format.json { render json: @endpoint.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end

  end
end
```

This is the Endpoint model:

```
class Endpoint < ApplicationRecord

 belongs_to :entity
 belongs_to :environment
 belongs_to :endpoint_app
 belongs_to :endpoint_type

 has_many :configs_histories

 has_paper_trail

end
```

The table in DB is:

```
create_table "endpoints", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "hostname"
   t.string   "username"
   t.string   "password"
   t.string   "connection_string"
   t.integer  "entity_id"
   t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
   t.integer  "endpoint_type_id"
   t.integer  "endpoint_app_id"
   t.integer  "environment_id"
   t.integer  "created_by"
   t.integer  "updated_by"
   t.integer  "version"
   t.index ["endpoint_app_id"], name: "index_endpoints_on_endpoint_app_id"
   t.index ["endpoint_type_id"], name: "index_endpoints_on_endpoint_type_id"
   t.index ["entity_id"], name: "index_endpoints_on_entity_id"
   t.index ["environment_id"], name: "index_endpoints_on_environment_id"
 end
```

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the command `e.save` work?

Comment: What are the `params` generated in the server log?

Comment: The `params` in server log are: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"4B+JMpFIdmp089gUvCle/+WlNzeAxP6Fy435olXxXt54n+RGAhbDQ+iEiVZOVZnW+D1zODRZsQDgSS7LS1MyiQ==", "env"=>"1", "endpoint"=>{"entity_id"=>"811", "endpoint_type_id"=>"2", "endpoint_app_id"=>"1", "hostname"=>"andromeda2005", "username"=>"andromeda2005", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "connection_string"=>"andromeda2005", "environment_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Gravar", "id"=>"9922"}`

Comment: Well there is no `verison` coming in the `params` hash, hence it didn't got saved or we can say *saved as `nil`*

Comment: Ok I see you are appending `version` manually in the controller.

Comment: @Ayanami check my post..it will work.

Comment: @Ayanami as no version in hash and you calculate it in controller, you have to pass it in params hash.

Comment: I'm betting on `e.save` failing silently because of validations or something. Try `e.save!` and it should fail more loudly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

`version` is a reserved keyword so it can't be used as a column name.

check link: http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words?page=9

Comment: There is no `version` coming in the `params` hash!

Comment: @Pavan version_no is calculated in controller

Comment: I mean this `params[:endpoint][:version]` won't work since there is no `version` coming in the `params`

Comment: @Pavan yes its not in params, its calculated in controller `version_no = (EndpointsFile.where("environment_id = ?", @environment.id).maximum('version') || 0) + 1`

Comment: You didn't get my point! `params[:endpoint][:version]` will be `nil` So you are actually doing `nil = version_no`

Comment: providing the solution directly without verifying yourself and constantly asking it to approve is not the spirit here, you must also explain `why`?

Comment: @Pavan suppose a variable `a=nil`, can we assign a value to `a` like `a=5`, its not `nil=5`.

Comment: @Pavan: I don't see what you're trying to say. How will it not work?

Comment: @puneet18 your solution doesn't work :( The e.version still gets nil in the each loop.

Comment: @Ayanami where are you calculating version_no?

Comment: @Ayanami `@endpoint.version = version_no` is the code of calc version_no and want to save in db???

Comment: Here `version_no = (EndpointsFile.where("environment_id = ?", @environment.id).maximum('version') || 0) + 1` and it calculates correctly, the variable `version_no` is always with the correct version no.

Comment: I save in DB here: `@endpoints.each do |e|

            e.version = version_no
            e.save

            puts "e.version: #{e.version}"

          end`

Comment: @Ayanami add code `params[:endpoint][:version] = version_no` before update command, it pass version_no in params hash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146519/discussion-between-ayanami-and-puneet18).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I mean the `version_no` can be assigned to `params[:endpoint][:version]` directly? Since there is no `:version` key in the `params` hash it is `nil` right?

Comment: @Pavan: are you sure you know how hashes work? :) `h = {}; h[:version] = 2` This should not fail, right?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev How I missed it? I need a break! :D

Comment: @Pavan params[:endpoint][:version] = 5, it add  key `:version` in `params[:endpoint]` with value 5. Isn't it?

Comment: Thanks @puneet18, the problem was indeed the version being a reserved word. I renamed it and problem solved! Thank you and thank you to everyone for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calculating `version_no` inside `update`, you don't have to pass it in controller or permit in strong parameters, just do the following

```
@endpoint.update(endpoint_params.merge(version: version_no))
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and it doesn't work either :( The e.version still gets nil in the each loop.

Comment: try `e.save!` there's some validation that's failing

Comment: Version is a reserved word, check the accepted answer. Thank you for you time!

Comment: ohh i see.. (y)